# Data from api is not reflecting when that data is passed to setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made a request to an api, when I console log the data, it is showing the data , but the setItemsList(data) is set to empty.

In the component the itemsList value is not received.

I searched for this and the problem I found is "You made an asynchronous request to an API, the request (e.g. Promise) isn't resolved yet, but you unmount the component. Then the request resolves, this.setState() is called to set the new state, but it hits an unmounted component."  But I am unable to resolve this issue

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useProductsList = () => {
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetch("http://localhost:4000/items")
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setItemsList(data);
          console.log("il", itemsList);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("Err occured", err));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return {
    itemsList,
    setItemsList,
  };
};
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useItemsList } from "./hooks/useItemsList";

// import ImageDisplay from "../components/item/ImageDisplay";

const Item = () => {
  const { itemsList } = useItemsList();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  console.log(itemsList);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(() =>
      itemsList?.filter((prod) => parseInt(prod.id) === parseInt(id))
    );
    console.log("PRODUCT", product);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid" }}>
      <div>{/* <ImageDisplay product={productArr[0]} /> */}</div>
      <div>
        <p>{product[0].title}</p>
         <p>{product[0].description}</p>
        <p>{product[0].rating} / 5</p>
        <hr></hr>
        <p>{product[0].price}</p>
        <p>{product[0].discount}</p> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to test to see if `itemLists` is getting any data at all,  this will let you know if you are returning `itemLists` before the data is set.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //Will console log when itemsList is updated
    console.log("Updated itemsList:", itemsList);
  }, [itemsList]);
```